# Plot all points that statisfy a predicate scilab

Tags: plot, scilab

I have function **P** which takes two points and returns true if they satisfy some condition, false otherwise. I want to plot all the points in range `lx <= x <= hx, ly <= y <= hy` that satisfy the condition. How to do this in scilab?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A combination of [ndgrid](http://help.scilab.org/docs/5.5.2/en_US/ndgrid.html) and the [find](http://help.scilab.org/docs/5.5.2/en_US/find.html) function is exactly suited for this. For instance:

```
lx = 0;
hx = 10;

ly = 0;
hy = 10;

// Create x and y lists
a = linspace(lx,hx);
b = linspace(ly,hy);

// Create arrays for function evaluation on a 2D grid
[A,B] = ndgrid(a,b)

// Define your predicate as a function
function result = P(a, b)
    result = (a < b);
endfunction

// Evaluate your function for all values in A and B and as a result
// get a matrix p filled with booleans
p = P(A(:),B(:));

// Find all indices of TRUE
indices = find(p);

// Plot all points using A as x coordinate and B as y coordinate
plot(A(indices), B(indices), 'o')

// Scale the axis of the plot so that all points are visible
a=gca();
a.data_bounds = [lx,ly;hx,hy];
```

This will result in the plot below:

[image: a < b]